# REST API - Can not convert XML with JAXB

Tags: java, rest, jaxb

I have a problem with processing an API response. First I am making a connection to get my response:

```
HttpResponse<String> response = Unirest.get(buildUrl(newOrdersUrl)).basicAuth(login, pass).asString();
        if(response.getStatus() == 200){
            return OrdersConverter.convertOrders(response.getBody());
        } else {
            return null;
        }
```

With:

```
public class OrdersConverter {
    public static OrdersType convertOrders(String response) {
        try {
            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(OrdersType.class);
            Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
            StringBuffer xmlStr = new StringBuffer(response);

            JAXBElement<OrdersType> o = u.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xmlStr.toString())), OrdersType.class);

            return o.getValue();
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

With this https://sell.fruugo.com/fruugo-docs/fruugo-product-feed.xsd as Schema

My response String looks like this (with redacted Information)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<o:orders merchantId="Redacted" xmlns:o="https://www.fruugo.com/orders/schema">
    <o:order>
        <o:customerOrderId>Redacted</o:customerOrderId>
        <o:orderId>Redacted</o:orderId>
        <o:orderDate>Redacted</o:orderDate>
        <o:orderReleaseDate>Redacted</o:orderReleaseDate>
        <o:orderStatus>Redacted</o:orderStatus>
        <o:customerLanguageCode>Redacted</o:customerLanguageCode>
        <o:shippingAddress>
            <o:firstName>Redacted</o:firstName>
            <o:lastName>Redacted</o:lastName>
            <o:streetAddress>Redacted</o:streetAddress>
            <o:city>Redacted</o:city>
            <o:province>Redacted</o:province>
            <o:postalCode>Redacted</o:postalCode>
            <o:countryCode>Redacted</o:countryCode>
            <o:phoneNumber>Redacted</o:phoneNumber>
        </o:shippingAddress>
        <o:shippingMethod>Redacted</o:shippingMethod>
        <o:shippingCostInclVAT>Redacted</o:shippingCostInclVAT>
        <o:shippingCostVAT>Redacted</o:shippingCostVAT>
        <o:orderLines>
            <o:orderLine>
                <o:productId>Redacted</o:productId>
                <o:skuId>Redacted</o:skuId>
                <o:skuName>Redacted</o:skuName>
                <o:fruugoProductId>Redacted</o:fruugoProductId>
                <o:fruugoSkuId>Redacted</o:fruugoSkuId>
                <o:currencyCode>Redacted</o:currencyCode>
                <o:itemPriceInclVat>Redacted</o:itemPriceInclVat>
                <o:itemVat>Redacted</o:itemVat>
                <o:totalPriceInclVat>Redacted</o:totalPriceInclVat>
                <o:totalVat>Redacted</o:totalVat>
                <o:vatPercentage>Redacted</o:vatPercentage>
                <o:totalNumberOfItems>Redacted</o:totalNumberOfItems>
                <o:pendingItems>Redacted</o:pendingItems>
                <o:confirmedItems>Redacted</o:confirmedItems>
                <o:shippedItems>Redacted</o:shippedItems>
                <o:cancelledItems>Redacted</o:cancelledItems>
                <o:returnAnnouncedItems>Redacted</o:returnAnnouncedItems>
                <o:returnedItems>Redacted</o:returnedItems>
                <o:itemsWithException>Redacted</o:itemsWithException>
            </o:orderLine>
        </o:orderLines>
    </o:order>
    <o:order>
        <o:customerOrderId>Redacted</o:customerOrderId>
        <o:orderId>Redacted</o:orderId>
        <o:orderDate>Redacted</o:orderDate>
        <o:orderReleaseDate>Redacted</o:orderReleaseDate>
        <o:orderStatus>Redacted</o:orderStatus>
        <o:customerLanguageCode>Redacted</o:customerLanguageCode>
        <o:shippingAddress>
            <o:firstName>Redacted</o:firstName>
            <o:lastName>Redacted</o:lastName>
            <o:streetAddress>Redacted</o:streetAddress>
            <o:city>Redacted</o:city>
            <o:province>Redacted</o:province>
            <o:postalCode>Redacted</o:postalCode>
            <o:countryCode>Redacted</o:countryCode>
            <o:phoneNumber>Redacted</o:phoneNumber>
        </o:shippingAddress>
        <o:shippingMethod>Redacted</o:shippingMethod>
        <o:shippingCostInclVAT>Redacted</o:shippingCostInclVAT>
        <o:shippingCostVAT>Redacted</o:shippingCostVAT>
        <o:orderLines>
            <o:orderLine>
                <o:productId>Redacted</o:productId>
                <o:skuId>Redacted</o:skuId>
                <o:skuName>Redacted</o:skuName>
                <o:fruugoProductId>Redacted</o:fruugoProductId>
                <o:fruugoSkuId>Redacted</o:fruugoSkuId>
                <o:currencyCode>Redacted</o:currencyCode>
                <o:itemPriceInclVat>Redacted</o:itemPriceInclVat>
                <o:itemVat>Redacted</o:itemVat>
                <o:totalPriceInclVat>Redacted</o:totalPriceInclVat>
                <o:totalVat>Redacted</o:totalVat>
                <o:vatPercentage>Redacted</o:vatPercentage>
                <o:totalNumberOfItems>Redacted</o:totalNumberOfItems>
                <o:pendingItems>Redacted</o:pendingItems>
                <o:confirmedItems>Redacted</o:confirmedItems>
                <o:shippedItems>Redacted</o:shippedItems>
                <o:cancelledItems>Redacted</o:cancelledItems>
                <o:returnAnnouncedItems>Redacted</o:returnAnnouncedItems>
                <o:returnedItems>Redacted</o:returnedItems>
                <o:itemsWithException>Redacted</o:itemsWithException>
            </o:orderLine>
        </o:orderLines>
    </o:order>
    <o:order>
        <o:customerOrderId>Redacted</o:customerOrderId>
        <o:orderId>Redacted</o:orderId>
        <o:orderDate>Redacted</o:orderDate>
        <o:orderReleaseDate>Redacted</o:orderReleaseDate>
        <o:orderStatus>Redacted</o:orderStatus>
        <o:customerLanguageCode>Redacted</o:customerLanguageCode>
        <o:shippingAddress>
            <o:firstName>Redacted</o:firstName>
            <o:lastName>Redacted</o:lastName>
            <o:streetAddress>Redacted</o:streetAddress>
            <o:city>Redacted</o:city>
            <o:province>Redacted</o:province>
            <o:postalCode>Redacted</o:postalCode>
            <o:countryCode>Redacted</o:countryCode>
            <o:phoneNumber>Redacted</o:phoneNumber>
        </o:shippingAddress>
        <o:shippingMethod>Redacted</o:shippingMethod>
        <o:shippingCostInclVAT>Redacted</o:shippingCostInclVAT>
        <o:shippingCostVAT>Redacted</o:shippingCostVAT>
        <o:orderLines>
            <o:orderLine>
                <o:productId>Redacted</o:productId>
                <o:skuId>Redacted</o:skuId>
                <o:skuName>Redacted</o:skuName>
                <o:fruugoProductId>Redacted</o:fruugoProductId>
                <o:fruugoSkuId>Redacted</o:fruugoSkuId>
                <o:currencyCode>Redacted</o:currencyCode>
                <o:itemPriceInclVat>Redacted</o:itemPriceInclVat>
                <o:itemVat>Redacted</o:itemVat>
                <o:totalPriceInclVat>Redacted</o:totalPriceInclVat>
                <o:totalVat>Redacted</o:totalVat>
                <o:vatPercentage>Redacted</o:vatPercentage>
                <o:totalNumberOfItems>Redacted</o:totalNumberOfItems>
                <o:pendingItems>Redacted</o:pendingItems>
                <o:confirmedItems>Redacted</o:confirmedItems>
                <o:shippedItems>Redacted</o:shippedItems>
                <o:cancelledItems>Redacted</o:cancelledItems>
                <o:returnAnnouncedItems>Redacted</o:returnAnnouncedItems>
                <o:returnedItems>Redacted</o:returnedItems>
                <o:itemsWithException>Redacted</o:itemsWithException>
            </o:orderLine>
        </o:orderLines>
    </o:order>
</o:orders>
```

When I convert this response to OrdersType.class I can get my merchantID but I do not get a List of Orders from the OrdersType.class.
What am I missing? Do I need to convert this response to another class to get the list of orders?

UPDATE:

ObjectFactory

```
/**
 * This object contains factory methods for each 
 * Java content interface and Java element interface 
 * generated in the model package. 
 * <p>An ObjectFactory allows you to programatically 
 * construct new instances of the Java representation 
 * for XML content. The Java representation of XML 
 * content can consist of schema derived interfaces 
 * and classes representing the binding of schema 
 * type definitions, element declarations and model 
 * groups.  Factory methods for each of these are 
 * provided in this class.
 * 
 */
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    private final static QName _Orders_QNAME = new QName("https://www.fruugo.com/orders/schema", "orders");

    /**
     * Create a new ObjectFactory that can be used to create new instances of schema derived classes for package: model
     * 
     */
    public ObjectFactory() {
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link ShippingAddressType }
     * 
     */
    public ShippingAddressType createShippingAddressType() {
        return new ShippingAddressType();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link OrderLinesType }
     * 
     */
    public OrderLinesType createOrderLinesType() {
        return new OrderLinesType();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link OrderType }
     * 
     */
    public OrderType createOrderType() {
        return new OrderType();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link ShipmentLinesType }
     * 
     */
    public ShipmentLinesType createShipmentLinesType() {
        return new ShipmentLinesType();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link ShipmentType }
     * 
     */
    public ShipmentType createShipmentType() {
        return new ShipmentType();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link ShipmentsType }
     * 
     */
    public ShipmentsType createShipmentsType() {
        return new ShipmentsType();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link ShipmentLineType }
     * 
     */
    public ShipmentLineType createShipmentLineType() {
        return new ShipmentLineType();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link AttributeType }
     * 
     */
    public AttributeType createAttributeType() {
        return new AttributeType();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link AttributesType }
     * 
     */
    public AttributesType createAttributesType() {
        return new AttributesType();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link OrdersType }
     * 
     */
    public OrdersType createOrdersType() {
        return new OrdersType();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link OrderLineType }
     * 
     */
    public OrderLineType createOrderLineType() {
        return new OrderLineType();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link OrdersType }{@code >}}
     * 
     */
    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "https://www.fruugo.com/orders/schema", name = "orders")
    public static JAXBElement<OrdersType> createOrders(OrdersType value) {
        return new JAXBElement<OrdersType>(_Orders_QNAME, OrdersType.class, null, value);
    }

}
```

OrdersType

```
/**
 * <p>Java class for OrdersType complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="OrdersType">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="order" type="{https://www.fruugo.com/orders/schema}OrderType" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *       &lt;attribute name="version" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" />
 *       &lt;attribute name="merchantId" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" />
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "OrdersType", propOrder = {
    "order"
})
public class OrdersType {

    protected List<OrderType> order;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "version")
    protected String version;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "merchantId")
    protected String merchantId;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the order property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
     * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
     * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
     * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the order property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
     * <pre>
     *    getOrder().add(newItem);
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     * <p>
     * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
     * {@link OrderType }
     * 
     * 
     */
    public List<OrderType> getOrder() {
        if (order == null) {
            order = new ArrayList<OrderType>();
        }
        return this.order;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the version property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the version property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setVersion(String value) {
        this.version = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the merchantId property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getMerchantId() {
        return merchantId;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the merchantId property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setMerchantId(String value) {
        this.merchantId = value;
    }

}
```

OrderType

```
/**
 * <p>Java class for OrderType complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="OrderType">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="orderId" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
 *         &lt;element name="orderDate" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}dateTime"/>
 *         &lt;element name="orderReleaseDate" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}dateTime"/>
 *         &lt;element name="orderStatus" type="{https://www.fruugo.com/orders/schema}OrderStatusEnumType"/>
 *         &lt;element name="customerLanguageCode" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
 *         &lt;element name="shippingAddress" type="{https://www.fruugo.com/orders/schema}ShippingAddressType"/>
 *         &lt;element name="shippingMethod" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
 *         &lt;element name="shippingCostInclVAT" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}float"/>
 *         &lt;element name="shippingCostVAT" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}float"/>
 *         &lt;element name="orderLines" type="{https://www.fruugo.com/orders/schema}OrderLinesType"/>
 *         &lt;element name="shipments" type="{https://www.fruugo.com/orders/schema}ShipmentsType" minOccurs="0"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "OrderType", propOrder = {
    "orderId",
    "orderDate",
    "orderReleaseDate",
    "orderStatus",
    "customerLanguageCode",
    "shippingAddress",
    "shippingMethod",
    "shippingCostInclVAT",
    "shippingCostVAT",
    "orderLines",
    "shipments"
})
public class OrderType {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String orderId;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar orderDate;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar orderReleaseDate;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected OrderStatusEnumType orderStatus;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String customerLanguageCode;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected ShippingAddressType shippingAddress;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String shippingMethod;
    protected float shippingCostInclVAT;
    protected float shippingCostVAT;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected OrderLinesType orderLines;
    protected ShipmentsType shipments;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the orderId property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the orderId property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setOrderId(String value) {
        this.orderId = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the orderDate property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link XMLGregorianCalendar }
     *     
     */
    public XMLGregorianCalendar getOrderDate() {
        return orderDate;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the orderDate property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link XMLGregorianCalendar }
     *     
     */
    public void setOrderDate(XMLGregorianCalendar value) {
        this.orderDate = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the orderReleaseDate property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link XMLGregorianCalendar }
     *     
     */
    public XMLGregorianCalendar getOrderReleaseDate() {
        return orderReleaseDate;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the orderReleaseDate property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link XMLGregorianCalendar }
     *     
     */
    public void setOrderReleaseDate(XMLGregorianCalendar value) {
        this.orderReleaseDate = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the orderStatus property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link OrderStatusEnumType }
     *     
     */
    public OrderStatusEnumType getOrderStatus() {
        return orderStatus;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the orderStatus property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link OrderStatusEnumType }
     *     
     */
    public void setOrderStatus(OrderStatusEnumType value) {
        this.orderStatus = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the customerLanguageCode property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getCustomerLanguageCode() {
        return customerLanguageCode;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the customerLanguageCode property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setCustomerLanguageCode(String value) {
        this.customerLanguageCode = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the shippingAddress property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link ShippingAddressType }
     *     
     */
    public ShippingAddressType getShippingAddress() {
        return shippingAddress;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the shippingAddress property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link ShippingAddressType }
     *     
     */
    public void setShippingAddress(ShippingAddressType value) {
        this.shippingAddress = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the shippingMethod property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getShippingMethod() {
        return shippingMethod;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the shippingMethod property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setShippingMethod(String value) {
        this.shippingMethod = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the shippingCostInclVAT property.
     * 
     */
    public float getShippingCostInclVAT() {
        return shippingCostInclVAT;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the shippingCostInclVAT property.
     * 
     */
    public void setShippingCostInclVAT(float value) {
        this.shippingCostInclVAT = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the shippingCostVAT property.
     * 
     */
    public float getShippingCostVAT() {
        return shippingCostVAT;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the shippingCostVAT property.
     * 
     */
    public void setShippingCostVAT(float value) {
        this.shippingCostVAT = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the orderLines property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link OrderLinesType }
     *     
     */
    public OrderLinesType getOrderLines() {
        return orderLines;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the orderLines property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link OrderLinesType }
     *     
     */
    public void setOrderLines(OrderLinesType value) {
        this.orderLines = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the shipments property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link ShipmentsType }
     *     
     */
    public ShipmentsType getShipments() {
        return shipments;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the shipments property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link ShipmentsType }
     *     
     */
    public void setShipments(ShipmentsType value) {
        this.shipments = value;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that this question will be hard to answer without details about OrdersType.

Comment: @jokster I thought with the .xsd you could create your own OrdersType.class. I will edit OrdersType, Objectfactory and OrderType

Comment: The outcome of generating it my depend a lot on settings.

Comment: @jokster ok... do you have examples for me. I am out of options to try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty sure that the problem is that the structure of the xml (response) does not match the generated classes.

The xsd you provided does not correspond with the classes you provided in the question nor with the xml you try to unmarshal. I think you have some bindings that override the names, etc. of the schema shown in the link, and not all classes are provided to try it on my own.

A way to help you figure it out is to feed the xml and try to unmarshal it with the following code and you will get feedback field by field for the mismatches.

```
        try {
            File file = new File("/path/to/your/file.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(YouRootClassForOrder.class);

            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            jaxbUnmarshaller.setEventHandler(
                    new ValidationEventHandler() {
                        public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event ) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(event.getMessage(),
                                    event.getLinkedException());
                        }
                    });
            YouRootClassForOrder pojo = (YouRootClassForOrder) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Yes. thanks for this info. The solution was to generate the model again, to fix the namespace problem.